# After git hard reset, changes are not detected anymore

Tags: git, github

I have two branchs develop and master. Someone accidently merge master to develop and some of changes in develop are gone. So I hard reset the develop to two commit back (that is working one) but after I hard reset, some of change in current commit are not detected anymore. Here is step by step

Step 1. Working

```
develop            E---F---G
                  /
master   A---B---C---D
```

Step 2. Merge master to develop, some changes are gone/overwrite (I am not very sure why)

```
develop           E---D
                 /
master   A---B---C---D
```

Step 3. Develop Hard reset to G in local, looks like we got the working one back

```
develop           E---F---G
                 /
master   A---B---C---D
```

Step 4. Push to remote develop branch to update (so remote develop also at G) and tested it working.

Step 5. Try to merge the develop to master, but some change in develop are not detect anymore (e.g. E and F changes are not detect, only merge G)

If I use the `git diff`, I can see the file different but its not shown in changes.

Question

- Changes are not detect anymore is because of Hard reset?
- How can I make manually make/detect change in develop and merge to master even though it doesn't show in changes?

Comment: can you please explain in more details what changes you expect to see, and how you know they don't show up anymore ? (for example: please provide the complete `git diff` command you use to check differences)

Comment: @LeGEC, I used `gif diff <commit of current develop branch> <commit of current master branch>` .  If I use that it can show 7 files are different which are changes in develop branch. but if I merge develop to master, these changes are not updated into master.

Comment: this may be expected. For example: if `develop` brings changes to `feature.py`, you don't want the merge to keep that version. It is also not entirely clear from your question what you intend by "merge", can you please describe that ? (`git merge` from the command line, clicking "Merge" on a Pull Request interface ...)

Comment: @LeGEC , I am using `Merge` on a Pull Request in github itself. Not by the cmd.

Comment: That's an important information, please update your question with it. Also: there is a setting on your github repository saying what action is actually done when you press Merge: can be merge, squash merge ... add this information too

Comment: I also realize I couldn't fully make sense of your comment "these changes are not updated into master". What `diff` command do you check after the merge ?

Comment: @LeGEC, In github repository there is only said "Merge" like normal merge PR. And after that I check the master branch whether updated or not by manually open the file and it does not updated which are changed in develop branch. I used `git diff` command with last commit of master and develop.

Answer (score 0):

when master merged into developer, changes on developer branch had gone forever.you can't get it back by git. if your IDE is Intelligent Idea, you can refer to local history , it can help you restored changes never stored.